# GRPC connection unavailable for Docker

Tags: docker

We are getting GRPC connection unavailable error suddenly in middle when containers are up and running properly and we have seen docker restart as workaround but it is not recommended in our environment since docker restart will break the state of functionality.

Environment details:

OS - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)

Kernel - Linux 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 21 18:14:51 EDT 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Docker - Docker version 1.13.1, build 94f4240/1.13.1

Containerd - containerd version 0.2.3

Storage Driver - overlay2

Thanks

Comment: "We are getting GRPC connection unavailable error suddenly in middle" - middle of what?

Comment: Container will be running fine and suddenly we see this error when we try to login to container.

Comment: You need to be more precise. Try to describe your setup, the error you're getting and the situation you get it in the best you can. Possibly with code snippets and logs (anonimized). And BTW you need to call me with @jannis if you want me to get notified about your comment. I saw your reply by accident.